# Add JSON object to Another JSON Object at particular place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JSON Objects:

```
var JSonData = {"li_ZPI":{},"li_ZIN":{"li_ISD":{},"li_AAH":{"li_AAD":{}},"li_EAH":{"li_EAD":{}},"li_REG":{},"li_PSC":{},"li_IMC":{},"li_GSP":{},"li_IES":{}}};
```

and

```
var additionalJSonData = {"li_AAH_1":{"li_AAD_1":{}}};
```

I want to add `additionalJSonData` object after JSONData `"li_AAH"` Object.

Comment: You do not have JSON objects.  You have JavaScript objects.  JSON is a data transport format (like XML or CSV).  It's a *string representation* of data.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can easily do it using `$.extend()` function:

```
$.extend(true, JSonData,additionalJSonData);
```

In any other frameworks, there are similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no *after*. These "JSON" objects (Javascript objects, really, JSON would be text strings that could *convert* to JS objects) are hashes, not arrays. Hashes have no order - that is,

```
for ( var f in JSonData ) {
}
```

there's no rule that the various keys (`"li_ZPI"`, etc.) would show up in any particular order, or even the *same* order each time.

So you can certainly add the new item:

```
JSonData["li_AAH_1"] = {"li_AAD_1":{}};
```

but don't expect the eventual JSON string to be ordered the way you're hoping.