# How to add json field to required json and at particular place using groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

I have the following json:

```
def desiredJson = '{"count": 4, "max": "12", "min": 0, "details": [{"goBus": {"first": 12800, "second": 11900, "third": 12800},"goAir": {"first": 12800, "second": 11900, "third": 12800}, "gotTrain": {"first": 12800, "second": 11900},"sell": true, "darn": 2,"rate": [{ "busRate": 11900, "flag": false, "percent": 0}],}],}'
```

I want to add `"total": "1000"` key-value pair after `"sell": true`.

So far I have tried following:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(desiredJson)
json.put('total', '1000')
log.info JsonOutput.toJson(json)
```

But it appends this pair at any place. Like this:

```
{
"count": 4,
"details": [{
    "darn": 2,
    "goAir": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    },
    "goBus": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    },
    "gotTrain": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900
    },
    "rate": [{
        "busRate": 11900,
        "flag": false,
        "percent": 0
    }],
    "sell": true
}],
"max": "12",
"min": 0,
"total": "1000"
}
```

Can we add it at any particular position? I have gone through this question which was already asked - [Add JSON object to Another JSON Object at particular place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264451/add-json-object-to-another-json-object-at-particular-place) . But I couldn't get any clue from this.

Also if this desiredJson has repetitive object like this:

```
{
"count": 4,
"details": [{
    "darn": 2,
    "goAir": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    },
    "goBus": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900,
        "third": 12800
    },
    "gotTrain": {
        "first": 12800,
        "second": 11900
    },
    "rate": [{
        "busRate": 11900,
        "flag": false,
        "percent": 0
    }],
    "sell": true
}],
"max": "12",
"min": 0,
"total": "1000"
},
{
"count": 5,
"details": [{
    "darn": 3,
    "goAir": {
        "first": 800,
        "second": 1100,
        "third": 1200
    },
    "goBus": {
        "first": 1200,
        "second": 100,
        "third": 1280
    },
    "gotTrain": {
        "first": 100,
        "second": 1900
    },
    "rate": [{
        "busRate": 1190,
        "flag": false,
        "percent": 1
    }],
    "sell": true
}],
"max": "14",
"min": 0,
"total": "1001"
},
{
"count": 6,
"details": [{
    "darn": 5,
    "goAir": {
        "first": 1800,
        "second": 1100,
        "third": 1280
    },
    "goBus": {
        "first": 1280,
        "second": 1190,
        "third": 1280
    },
    "gotTrain": {
        "first": 1280,
        "second": 1100
    },
    "rate": [{
        "busRate": 900,
        "flag": false,
        "percent": 7
    }],
    "sell": true
}],
"max": "19",
"min": 0,
"total": "1002"
}
```

total key's value should be added and incremented both.

Comment: `desiredJson` with repetitive objects is not a valid JSON document. Can you edit your question and paste correct desired JSON document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - if you want to repeat JSON object in the document, you have to put it into array. In your case valid JSON document would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "count": 4,
    "details": [
      {
        "darn": 2,
        "goAir": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900,
          "third": 12800
        },
        "goBus": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900,
          "third": 12800
        },
        "gotTrain": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900
        },
        "rate": [
          {
            "busRate": 11900,
            "flag": false,
            "percent": 0
          }
        ],
        "sell": true
      }
    ],
    "max": "12",
    "min": 0
  },
  {
    "count": 4,
    "details": [
      {
        "darn": 2,
        "goAir": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900,
          "third": 12800
        },
        "goBus": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900,
          "third": 12800
        },
        "gotTrain": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900
        },
        "rate": [
          {
            "busRate": 11900,
            "flag": false,
            "percent": 0
          }
        ],
        "sell": true
      }
    ],
    "max": "12",
    "min": 0
  },
  {
    "count": 4,
    "details": [
      {
        "darn": 2,
        "goAir": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900,
          "third": 12800
        },
        "goBus": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900,
          "third": 12800
        },
        "gotTrain": {
          "first": 12800,
          "second": 11900
        },
        "rate": [
          {
            "busRate": 11900,
            "flag": false,
            "percent": 0
          }
        ],
        "sell": true
      }
    ],
    "max": "12",
    "min": 0
  }
]
```

Now, if you want to add `total` field the each object in the array in path `$.details.total` then you can do something like that:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(desiredJson)

int total = 1000
json.details.each { it.get(0).put('total', total++) }

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json))
```

If you want to add `total` field to path `$.details.rate.total` then you do:

```
json.details.rate.each { it.flatten().get(0).put('total', total++) }
```

instead.

#### Output

```
[
    {
        "count": 4,
        "details": [
            {
                "darn": 2,
                "goAir": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900,
                    "third": 12800
                },
                "goBus": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900,
                    "third": 12800
                },
                "gotTrain": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900
                },
                "rate": [
                    {
                        "busRate": 11900,
                        "flag": false,
                        "percent": 0
                    }
                ],
                "sell": true,
                "total": 1000
            }
        ],
        "max": "12",
        "min": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 4,
        "details": [
            {
                "darn": 2,
                "goAir": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900,
                    "third": 12800
                },
                "goBus": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900,
                    "third": 12800
                },
                "gotTrain": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900
                },
                "rate": [
                    {
                        "busRate": 11900,
                        "flag": false,
                        "percent": 0
                    }
                ],
                "sell": true,
                "total": 1001
            }
        ],
        "max": "12",
        "min": 0
    },
    {
        "count": 4,
        "details": [
            {
                "darn": 2,
                "goAir": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900,
                    "third": 12800
                },
                "goBus": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900,
                    "third": 12800
                },
                "gotTrain": {
                    "first": 12800,
                    "second": 11900
                },
                "rate": [
                    {
                        "busRate": 11900,
                        "flag": false,
                        "percent": 0
                    }
                ],
                "sell": true,
                "total": 1002
            }
        ],
        "max": "12",
        "min": 0
    }
]
```

Keep in mind, that it adds `total` right after `sell` key, but from the JSON document validation perspective, it doesn't matter if this is before or after `sell` field. It shouldn't even matter when this document gets parsed by a consumer.

Comment: Ok, What if I want to add this total key inside "rate" array object. "rate": [
                    {
                        "busRate": 11900,
                        "flag": false,
                        "percent": 0, "total" : 1000
                    }
                ],

Comment: @avidCoder I've updated the answer. In this case you do `json.details.rate.each { it.flatten().get(0).put('total', total++) }` and get `total` field added using `$.details.rate.total` document path.

Comment: What can I help you with? I'm busy at the moment, but can answer your question later during the day.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, It is resolved now.. Was doing some silly mistake. Thanks you so much. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help you

Answer (score 2):

No you can't (well sure you can, but why bother).  Here is why:

> Object: an **unordered** collection of name–value pairs

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example)

So if something upstream *needs* to have this in order, then it's broken.

Comment: JSON structures can represent objects with strict order, like FHIR objects for example.